# The load event listener is not triggered after assign the url to an img's source inside a Promise

Tags: javascript, html, promise

I am writing a promise which takes a image's url as arugment. Then I want to do something after the image resource is fully loaded.

```
function retrieveImage(imageUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      // bunch of execution
      console.log('I am loaded.');
      resolve('something');
    });
    img.src = imageUrl;
  });
}
```

I expected after I do something like:

```
// Load google's logo.
const loadSomeImage = retrieveImage('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png');
```

The console will log 'I am loaded.' message. Instead, the console didn't show anything. Even further, the promise kept showing pending even after I checked the network activity panel on the firefox, which said the http GET is status 200.

This is the original function.

```
function retrieveImage(imageUrl) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.addEventListener('load', function (e) {
      // I want to draw the image into a canvas
      // and convert it into base64url.
      const canv = document.createElement('canvas');
      canv.width = this.width;
      canv.height = this.height;
      const ctx = canv.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      // The reason why I need set crossOrigin attr to anonymous is
      // because the following code. If I don't set that, I will get a
      // security warning and the code just doesn't proceed any further.
      resolve(canv.toDataURL());
    });
    img.src = imageUrl;
  });
}
```

Comment: Try to move this `img.src = imageUrl;` after `resolve('something');`

Comment: `img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';` remove that ... suddenly it works

Comment: @McBern ... `load` won't fire until an image finishes loading ... so, if what you are saying is put `img.src = ...` inside the load event handler, then you'd guarantee it would never work

Comment: Also make sure to catch any errors: `img.addEventListener( 'error', reject )` - otherwise your promise will never reject and a failure to load is not an exception that will stop your script.

Comment: what was the reason for including `img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Because I am requesting a source from different origin.

Comment: @somethinghere tks, I would do that.

Comment: @honesty1997 - and wanting to use them in a canvas perhaps? without all that bothersome "tainted" issue?

Comment: Okay, sorry for the late reply. Add ```img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';``` is because I want to further handle the image with canvas api. I will add the complete function in the original post.

Comment: @JaromandaX exactly.

Comment: if a site doesn't want to share it's resources that way, then you can't bypass it ... use your own server to "proxy" the required resource, and then you wont have any cross origin issues, as server to server requests are not bound by same origin rules

Comment: I added the original function at the end of the post.

Comment: @JaromandaX oh, just random asking. Assume my code worked somehow. Does the approach contain any potential security hole?

Comment: @honesty1997 Not really a security issue, just a fact that you are a cors-proxy and once people find out they might try to use your server for the same purpose. In all, it's best to be very specific with the content you serve. And best to not load and modify images from _other_ sources anyhow, unless they are CDNs, and they usually allow cross-origin.